# Why are some questions hi lighted in blue?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question that became very popular very quickly (1000 views in 1 day).

I noticed on the home page that it is now highlighted in blue. What does the hi light mean?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The highlight indicates you are following one of the tags that question has.